# Tensorflow: Error on optimizer initialization with custom var_list

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to optimize only a specific subset of my variables like so:

```
my_train = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001).minimize(my_loss, var_list=my_variables)
```

This gives me an error message

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ((None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f30317a5f10>), (None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f303146fa10>), (None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f3031522390>), (None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f30314e1dd0>), (None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f30314a5fd0>), (None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f303146ae90>))
```

There is no error if I leave out the var_list, but this obviously isn't what I want, and from the error message it isn't clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: The problem here is that TensorFlow can't find a backpropagation path from `my_loss` to any of the variables in `my_variables`. Are you sure that `my_loss` depends on those variables? Perhaps sharing a complete example would make the problem clearer.

Comment: My example is fairly complicated so I hesitate to post it all here. However tensorboard shows an edge labeled "six tensors" (which is the number of variables in my_scope) going from my_scope into my_loss.

Comment: If you expand the path between your variables and `my_loss`, what ops do you see? My guess is that there's something non-differentiable (e.g. a `tf.cast()`) that's preventing the gradients from backpropagating.

Comment: This is my first time using tensorboard, so I'm not sure how to expand paths. Clicking on it doesn't seem to do anything. In any case the only layers should be matmul, addition, sigmoid, tanh, and concat.

Comment: After figuring out that you expand name scopes and not edges, I got to the bottom of it. Indeed there was no connection between my_variables and my_loss due to a bug in my code. I found that adding name scopes everywhere helped a lot, and allowed me to find the bug. For the curious: a helper function was using global variables instead of its own arguments (which I didn't catch initially because I was passing those very global variables as the arguments) - and so my graph was wired incorrectly.